# dynamicType + cast to protocol leads to crash

Tags: swift, dynamictype

I have these classes:

**AppDataProtocol.swift**

```
public protocol AppDataProtocol{

    var logoImagePath : String! {get}
    var logoTitle : String? {get}
    var logoSubtitle : String? {get}

    var categories : [MainMenuOption]! {get}

    static func contentElements(filter: ContentFilter?) -> [ContentElement]!
}
```

**AppData.swift**

```
class AppData{

   static var sharedData : AppDataProtocol!

   init(){}

}
```

**CustomAppData.swift [Class that conforms to AppDataProtocol]**

```
class CustomAppData: AppData, AppDataProtocol {
// fulfills the AppDataProtocol, omitted for brevity
}
```

So with these classes given, I try to dynamically set the class variable like so:

```
AppData.sharedData = CustomAppData()
```

and access it like so:

```
// we need the class so we can call the class function
let appData = AppData.sharedData.dynamicType as! AppDataProtocol.Type 
/*^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^*/
                             /*CRASH!*/
let contentElements = appData.contentElements(nil)
```

By calling dynamicType on the instance stored in the class variable of AppData (sharedData) I should be getting the class that conforms to AppDataProtocol, right ? I think the problem is that dynamicType actually returns the Interface type (i.e. "AppDataProtocol") and I probably cannot call anything on that per se. Can somebody tell me why this doesn't work ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. `AppData.sharedData` is not initialised, and has no type, only a protocol you want it to conform to. Whether the rest of your forced downcast would ever work is moot...

Comment: @Grimxn It actually is initialized... Look  at the line in my question that says `AppData.sharedData = CustomAppData()`

Comment: Missed that. Why are you initialising it outside the class? Since you are doing that, you have to implicitly unwrap it, which means that `AppData.sharedData.dynamicType` is `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<AppDataProtocol>.Type` rather than `AppDataProtocol.Type` which is probably not what you expected...

Comment: @Grimxn Nevermind... I do that because I need to dynamically swap out data sources for a different module. I guess there are better ways for doing that, but I'll keep that for now. Yeah, exactly, how do I get around that issue ?

Comment: Make it an optional `AppDataProtocol?` rather than implicitly unwrapped `AppDataProtocol!` in the class, then you can unwrap it thus: `let appData = (AppData.sharedData!).dynamicType // "CustomAppData.Type"`, with no need to downcast.

Comment: @Grimxn Thanks a lot! That worked! Please write an answer so that I can reward you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP seems to wish to have a have a class variable that holds a `Type` (i.e. an actual class) that conforms to a protocol, but may be itself variable (i.e. hold different `Type`s of that protocol at different times).

The problem is that

```
class AppData{
   static var sharedData : AppDataProtocol
   init(){}
}
```

will not compile, as `sharedData` is not initialised. One fix for that is to make it implicitly unwrapped, as he has done in the question, trusting that when he does access it it *will* have been set. The problem with this is that when he actually accesses the variable's `dynamicType` it's not what he expects - it's actually `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<AppDataProtocol>.Type` rather than `AppDataProtocol.Type`.

The solution is simply to declare `static var sharedData : AppDataProtocol?` rather than `static var sharedData : AppDataProtocol!`, and then to unwrap it before calling `dynamicType`, thus:

`let appData = (AppData.sharedData!).dynamicType // "CustomAppData.Type"`

**OP** - feel free to edit if my assumption about your intent is off target...

Comment: You nailed it on the head. Thanks again!